# How to iterate over an abstract class's objects in a Django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have an abstract class Item and multiple product classes which inherit from Item. In my template, I want a for loop of every class that inherits from Item, but I don't want to rewrite a for loop for every class that inherits from Item. I want of for loop of the class Item which will give me every subclass that inherits from Item.

Answer (score 0):

#### one of ways, you could union all the queryset by itertools.chain

```
# views.py
import itertools
def handle(request):
    all_products = itertools.chain(qset_a, qset_b, qset_c)
    context = {'all_products':all_products}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Comment: I get a TypeError ('ModelBase' object is not iterable) when trying it out. I replaced qset_a with the name of one of my subclasses.

Comment: qset_a should be a queryset, like Product.objects.all() or filter(), not Product

Comment: thanks, it works. Now, is there a way to just chain all objects from models.py without worrying about adding a new query set each time that you add a new model?